# Creating command line tools in python

Tags: python, wordpress, command-line

i want to create some command line utilities to manage many wordpress site, allowing me to create, clone , move , wordpress sites.

Anyways, while i have the idea and how it will work, i wanted to know what will you recommend mind to start creating those, or any framework that i can use.

UPDATE:

Here are some more details on this tool:

- Will use mysql
- Will be installed on my local client, and will use Ftp to connect to all wordpress sites.

Comment: Are you moving them via FTP, SFTP or a local filesystem? Which databases are in use? MySQL I suppose? Or PostgreSQL? etc. You raising many question before there could be an answer...

Comment: So far Ftp, and Mysql by default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of managing wordpress one of the following libraries might be useful:

http://rufuspollock.org/2011/12/29/ann-pywordpress-python-wordpress-library-using-the-wordpress-xml-rpc-api/

http://www.blackbirdblog.it/programmazione/progetti/28

Comment: Thanks, i will accept your comment, but that is not really what i want(Though i will use as a base for mine)